# Rails string comparison fails on a hex string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm currently building an invite model that sends out email invitations with a link. The links are 'secured' with a sha1 hash. However, the controller fails to verify the hash and I can't figure out why...

Generated links look like

```
/projects/1/invitations/12?hash=c043b70c359a85e20cd9933c9cd37ef3f8943d7b
```

and the controller tries to verify them with

```
def show
    @invitation = Invitation.find(params[:id])
    if @invitation.hash.to_s != params[:hash].to_s
       redirect_to root_url
       ....
```

The string comparison fails every time. I've triple checked, but the strings seem perfectly identical.

EDIT: Some debugging information

```
logger.debug params
logger.debug @invitation.hash
```

results in the following output in the development.log

```
{"hash"=>"c043b70c359a85e20cd9933c9cd37ef3f8943d7b", "action"=>"show",
controller"=>"invitations", "project_id"=>"1", "id"=>"12"}
c043b70c359a85e20cd9933c9cd37ef3f8943d7b
```

Comment: I am not sure about the answer, but I recently implemented a similar invitation system. I modified the following tutorial to my needs - I think you might find it handy too.
http://railscasts.com/episodes/124-beta-invitations

Comment: Give us an example when the comparison fails. "puts" both @invitation.hash, and params[:hash]. Let's check :)

Comment: Also, this might have something to do with encoding. What if before the comparison you execute this on both strings? `.force_encoding(Encoding::BINARY)` (Unless the hex has already been encoded in some ASCII friendly way, eg. Base 64)

Comment: the .force_encoding returns a new error: undefined method `force_encoding' for 2957458837425720582:Fixnum. The original hash has been saved to the database in a string column, so I assumed it would be safe...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if `@invitation.hash` is not actually calling [`Object#hash`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-hash).

Comment: That would make sense, but the log-files seem to indicate that it is not a name collision

Comment: Dang it! You're right, I just renamed the column and now it works. Even though logs indicate the correct value of invitation.hash, the comparison uses the Object#hash. Thanks a lot!